# Running "pub install" for dart-html5-samples leads to weird errors

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I encountered some weird errors when running "pub install" for dart-html5-samples. The first one was:

```
Illegal argument(s): join(): part 0 was null, but part 1 was not.
```

The second one was:

```
Running pub install ...
Pub install failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Could not find package "unittest 0.0.0-r.13075" at http://pub.dartlang.org.
```

What's going on, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is:

```
Illegal argument(s): join(): part 0 was null, but part 1 was not.
```

That's because pubspec.yaml contained:

```
dependencies:
  htmlescape:
    sdk: htmlescape
```

htmlescape no longer comes with the SDK. Removing the dependency fixed the problem. I simply made a copy of htmlescape.dart in my lib directory. Eventually, I won't need my own copy once the following bug is fixed:

http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1657

The second error is:

```
Running pub install ...
Pub install failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Could not find package "unittest 0.0.0-r.13075" at http://pub.dartlang.org.
```

dart-html5-samples depends on vector_math which depends on unittest. I think they must have changed how unittest is loaded by pub. Running `pub update` fixed the problem.